# Como passar keywords arguments em python de uma forma mais simples?

Tags: python, pygame

Eu estou tentando criar a classe botão e tentando receber os argumentos que eu posso passar pro rect, so que se algum argumento for None e eu passar por exemplo `self.rect = pygame.Rect(x=x)` e o `x` for None da erro, então eu to fazendo assim:

```
if x: 
    self.rect_initial.x = x
```

pra cada uma das propriedades de rect. Tem como jogar isso num loop for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python é extremamente flexível quanto a forma tanto de passar quanto de receber argumentos de função.

para o que você quer, a melhor coisa parece ser fazer a chamada desejada (no caso do exemplo, o "rect") passando os parâmetros em um dicionário, em vez de de escrever o nome dos parâmetros na chamada.

Para isso, basta prefixar o dicionário com dois `**`.

Ou seja, em Python, `exemplo(a=1, b=2)` é  a mesma coisa que escrever:
`parametros = {"a":1, "b": 2}; exemplo(**parametros)`.

No caso de uma função que vá repassar só os parâmetros que não forem `None` para um Rect, é possível fazer algo assim:

```
def minha_func(x=None, y=None, centerx=None, centery=None, width=None, height=None):
    parametros = {}
    for variavel in "x y centerx centery width height".split():
        if locals()[variavel] is not None:
             parametros[variavel] = locals()[variavel]
    meu_rect  = pygame.Rect(**parametros)
```

Comment: Maravilhoso. Por isso gosto de Python, tem sempre algo novo pra aprender.